# Giving user list of available parameter selections for SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

I have a stored procedure where I need to just do the normal

```
EXEC @A = X, @B = Y
GO
```

etc. to return results of a stored procedure.

I am wondering if it is possible in SQL Server to give a list of possible choices for one of the parameters.

I am using SQL Server 2014 Management Studio.

Comment: You could put that in the documentation for the procedure.  Documentation?  What's that?

Comment: Who is going to see it? What kind of examples do you mean?  A set list of option or a datatype choice?

Comment: Meant to put 2014...oops

Comment: I previously was working with SAS stored processes, so I was kinda used to being able to connect a variable in dataset with a drop down list options. lets say variable A is a certain location from A to Z. I want to be able to show all the possible locations and be able to select one.

Comment: Sure: Select X from table where Y='A', or pass a parameter for Y

Comment: I mean right now I type in X if I want a parameter to have the value of X. I am wondering I can call the list of values from the table and present them while executing the stored process so I know what all the options are